# how to create function to filter content WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, plugins, filter

I am making a plugin here i need my plugin apply only for my WordPress post content 'p' tag. Like post content p tag is capital letter only but sites others p tag not capital. Sites others 'p' tag no need to apply my plugin. How can i make this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
If you are telling about filter the_content you can use this-
I hope this is usefull for you:

<?php add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name' ) ?>

OR

<?php add_filter( 'the_content', '$data' ) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Pukhraj suthar